# Improving performance of dictionary lookup for large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, performance

I'm struggling with performance when comparing a large amount of strings to a dictionary ([SOWPODS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOWPODS) converted to JSON and split into files by starting letter).

The JSON-files are currently stored in a directory like this:

```
words/
    a.json
    b.json
    ...
    z.json
```

An input string of `'test'` in my code results in the following array of strings.

```
[ 'test',
  'tes',
  'tet',
  'te',
  'tst',
  'ts',
  'tt',
  't',
  'est',
  'es',
  'et',
  'e',
  'st',
  's',
  'tets',
  'tts',
  'ets',
  'tset',
  'tse',
  'set',
  'se',
  'tste',
  'tte',
  'ste',
  'ttes',
  'ttse',
  'etst',
  'ett',
  'etts',
  'estt',
  'stt',
  'stet',
  'stte',
  'sett' ]
```

To determine which files are to be read, I loop through the alphabet checking which letters exist in the input string (`'test'`), e.g.:

```
var i;
['a', 'b', ..., 'z'].forEach(function(letter) {
    i = input.indexOf(letter);
    if(i !== -1) {
        // letter exists, process [letter].json
        // avoid reading the same file twice
        input[i] = '';
    }
});
```

Files read for the above example would be `t.json, e.json, s.json`.

The computation time for the above example is merely ~0.08s, but increases  quickly with the amount of strings in the array and the number of files processed.

Are there any immediate performance boosters you come to think of when seeing this example? Should I be using a database? Was splitting the JSON into files by starting letter the wrong choice? All answers are welcome!

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: what I would recommend is to use *Regex expression* to match the character, if you are searching through UI, you can *debounce* the search to ~300-500ms. giving you a effective time for a more character input search instead of every single keystroke looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah, of course evaluating a JSON file is going to be slow. Evaluating a lot of large JSON files is even slower.

You'll have better luck looking into HTML5 web databases (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.opendatabase.md.html). As far as I know, this is only working on Webkit browsers right now, but it will be implemented across the board in time.

As an alternative, getting rid of JSON in favor of something easier to parse will improve things a bit -- but don't expect magic results from this. You need a real database if you're going to be storing large amounts of data and looking them up.

A better alternative would be to get rid of all your client-side database logic and using AJAX to call something server-side to look it up in an SQL database there.

Comment: I don't really want to separate the client and the server, mainly because this is a free time, open source project. My question is really: Would I gain any noticeable performance in using an SQLite database (or equivalent) instead of JSON files? For context, not self-promotion: https://github.com/mateogianolio/scrabbler

Comment: "noticeable" is a few orders of magnitude less than what you would get.

Comment: Switching to SQLite did improve performance quite a bit, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you for your help!